# if-Else condition working with JSON format in Python to determine which raws to append to a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, if-statement

I am producing a dataset starting from a series of JSON files associated with a certain ID (`authors_df` contains a bunch of ids) and I am using `for` to do this.
I tried with a subset of authors and it works fine.

**The problem is that some of the id have have an incomplete Json file. Thus I tried to include some 'else' conditions to make the code work also with incomplete data (json files of length 0).**
the problem is that I don't know how to do.

I tried `if len(json_value['resonanceCategorizations']['1']['fullData']) > 0 else null`

but it does not work (`KeyError: '1'`). I guess I have to set a different condition encompassing JSON structure of the complete files rather than using `null`

here is my code, it all works but the problem is with the line with else null.

```
json_values_per_author = {}
datalist = []
datadict = {}

for index, row in authors_df.iterrows():
    #get the author
    author = row['author']
    print(author)

#build the url
url = f'http://keystone-db.default.svc.cluster.local:5000/keystonedb/profiles/resonance/categorization?profileId={author}&regionId=1'    

#get the json value
json_value = requests.get(url).json()
full_data = json_value['resonanceCategorizations']['1']['fullData'] if len(json_value['resonanceCategorizations']['1']['fullData']) > 0 else null

datalist.append({
    "author": author,

    "seed1": full_data[0]['seed'],

    "seed2": full_data[1]['seed'] if len(full_data) > 2 else 'NA',

    "seed3": full_data[2]['seed'] if len(full_data) > 3 else 'NA'

})
```

another thing I tried was

```
 z = {"000": [{"seed": 0, "globalSegmentId": 0, "globalSegmentName": "Nope", "regionId": 0, "resonance": 0, "isGlobal": true, "globalRegion": 1}]}


full_data = json_value['resonanceCategorizations']['1']['fullData'] if len(json_value['resonanceCategorizations']['1']['fullData']) > 0 else z
```

basically creating a "null" JSON value to input as a default if there is no data

alternatively, it would be fine if I could just avoid  appending the authors with no data.

Comment: based on the error it seems that `resonanceCategorizations` doesn't always have the key `1`, also `null` is not a valid term in Python, especially since you haven't defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having problems with missing keys in dictionary, have a look at returning default value from dictionary

```
get(key[, default])
Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.
```

So in your case it might look like

```
full_data = json_value.get('resonanceCategorizations', {}).get('1', {}).get('fullData')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, it is unclear which key was not found, if `'resonanceCategorizations'` or `'1'` is not found, you can not apply `len` to it.

There are two approaches you can take. The first one is to use the `dict.get` method. Consider the following example:

```py
my_dict = {"a": 1, "b":2}
print(my_dict["a"]) # prints 1
print(my_dict.get("a")) # prints 1
print(my_dict.get("a", None)) # prints 1
print(my_dict["c"]) # raises KeyError
print(my_dict.get("c")) # raises KeyError
print(my_dict.get("c", None)) # prints None
```

This way, you can check whether the given field exists in a dictionary, of course, you need to do this everytime you access a field, and handle if the output is None.

Another approach is to use a try-catch block.

```py
try:
    value = some_dictionary["a"]["b"]["c"]
except KeyError:
    value = None
```

The disadvantage of this method is that you do not know whether  `a`, `a.b` or `a.b.c` was missing.